# Wordpress Customizer image gallery

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add in an option in the admin panel that let's a user populate an image gallery that I've created.

Looking through the Customizer API, I see how to add options, but it's still not what I want.

Is it better to build a plugin? Any reference that's recommended?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple carousels you could use. As far as I know, there should be a plugin but not many. I reccommend using Bootstrap's carousel, though

Comment: Appreciated, but I am trying to build from scratch. Just for further learning, as I know there are a lot of free options.

Comment: If you need inspiration, there is a site called codepen with people's open code with stuff you might need. if you look at some of that code, maybe you could adapt some of the syntax and make something on your own